# How do I display something on a particular category page?

Tags: categories, pages, conditional-content

How would I display HTML conditional on a particular category page?

Say my permalinks to the category pages are

http://www.mysite.com/category/awesome-category

How would I cast the `<?php if ... ?>` to do this, and within what template of my theme?

I'm using WP 3.3.1.  If I need to provide more information I'll be happy to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(is_category('awesome-category')) echo "whoa awesome category here!!;
```

probably in category.php, but it really depends on the setup of your theme... if you are using a child theme, etc.  also you could create a special template just for that specific category.

category-awesome-category.php

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: possible category template name: category-awesome-category.php - http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: you're right. fixed.